# Javascript: Set element value?

Tags: javascript, html, label

I would like to set a value of a `<label>`, like so:

```
<label for="idname">Value here...</label>
```

with Javascript. I have already done this, for the `for` attribute:

```
element.setAttribute("for", "idname");
```

is there something like `element.setValue()` that I can use to set the value of the label? Thanks!

Comment: Please more info, value of which element? Cuz it is useless to set value of label

Comment: I meant set the value of the innerHTML, I have now learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2G6qE/1)**

Iterate through the label elements looking for the property `for="idname"` like this:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for( var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++ ){
 if( labels[i].outerHTML.indexOf('for="idname"') > -1){
  var UseLabelValue = labels[i].innerHTML;
  labels[i].innerHTML = "Replace Value";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label for="idname">Value here...</label>


<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML='new value';
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML

http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 0):

A label has no value. If you want to set the text, you may use

```
element.innerHTML = "some text";
```